# how to randomly select a list with a nested list

Tags: python, random, nested

Perhaps this a simple question with using list comprehension.  How do you randomly select an entire list from a nested list?  The randomly selected list should be in the same order it is in within the nested list.

[['10','32','66'], ['78','501','23'], ['15','48', '698']]

Say the random selection gave me the second list in the nested list: ['78', '501', '23']

Thanks for any help...newbie.

Comment: Whoops...forgot to add that.  I'm working in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `python`, you can use `random.choice()`

```
$ python
>>> import random
>>> random.choice([['10','32','66'], ['78','501','23'], ['15','48', '698']])
['10', '32', '66']
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, for example, you have Maths.random() :
Math.floor(Math.random()*11) -> random number between 0-10
So you do like this :

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
alert(yourarray[index]);
```

Generally, find in your language how to generate a random number, then just show by array[index] as i did it ;)

Comment: Thanks...I will use kev's answer.  I forgot to mention that it's python I'm working with.